# Different behaviour while catching Throwable and StackOverflowError

Tags: java, exception, nullpointerexception, throwable

I have the below two sets of code

First Set of code is as below:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    try {
        main(null);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
    }

    System.out.println("Value of args[0] is : "args[0]);
}
```

Output is :

```
Value of args[0] is : db
```

Second set of code is as below:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    try {
        main(null);
    } catch (StackOverflowError e) {

    }

    System.out.println(args[0]);
}
```

Output is :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.way2learnonline.ui.Demo.main(Demo.java:16)
```

In both cases I am passing a command line argument i.e. 'db'.
In first set of code I am catching Throwable in the catch block where I can access the command line argument i.e. `args[0]` (I can see the args[0] output in the console).

In second set of code I am catching the StackOverflowError where I can not access the args[0]. It is showing NullPointerException.

I am not able to understand the behavior of Java.

Why I can access args[0] in first case and why args is null in second case.

Can someone explain why java is behaving like this?

Comment: Please note that catching `StackOverflowError` in real projects is extremely bad practice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`StackOverflowError` will happen in both pieces of code.

The code catching `StackOverflowError` will handle it in the last recursive call of the method, but since the `catch` does nothing then the next line of code will be executed:

```
System.out.println(args[0]);
```

And this will throw a `NullPointerException` since `args` is `null` and you cannot access to `args[0]`.

The other one will handle every error or exception, including this `NullPointerException`, and it will go up through all the methods in the call, so the exection of the code will continue. Seems like you're passing as argument `"db"`, so that's what is printed.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case you are catching all Exceptions, so when you call `main` with a null value of `args` the resulting `NullPointerException` is caught and you don't see it.

In the second case you are only catching `StackOverflowError` so the `NullPointerException` that results from trying to access an element in a null array is not handled and you see the error.

It looks like you are just experimenting here, but it's worth saying that you should never catch `StackOverflowError` in 'real' code.